# Difference between scipy's griddata and RectBivariateSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

When interpolating in (e.g.) a 2D grid, one may use the function `griddata` (from the `scipy.interpolate` package) or, from the same package, the `RectBivariateSpline`.

Is any of them favourable over the other, and if so, why? To my knowledge, `griddata` can handle irregular shaped inputs whereas `RectBivariateSpline` can't.

Comment: What do you mean by "favourable"? Do you have a particular use-case in mind?

Comment: Indeed, there are a variety of interpolation functions, with some overlap, but only you can read the docs, play with them, and decide which is best for your particular problem (and then hope when you go from the test problem to the real problem that what was 'best' remains best).  The ability of griddata to handle non-mesh points can, of course, be a deciding factor by itself.

Comment: Another difference that is there is that griddata can work with complex valued data, while RectBivariateSpline cant... Going to look more into it now

Answer (score 0):

Okay I dont have an answer to the question since it is quite.. generic.. But for those that land on this page as well and want to play with the two functions.. in the code below you can test out the difference.

My own opinion is that RectBivariateSpline works better by looking at the error plots. Also the way how to input data is more convenient, atleast in this usecase.

```
import scipy.interpolate
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d_coarse = 0.5
X_coarse = np.arange(-5, 5, d_coarse)
Y_coarse = np.arange(-5, 5, d_coarse)
X_fine = np.arange(-5, 5, d_coarse/2)
Y_fine = np.arange(-5, 5, d_coarse/2)

X_coarse_mesh, Y_coarse_mesh = np.meshgrid(X_coarse, Y_coarse)
X_fine_mesh, Y_fine_mesh = np.meshgrid(X_fine, Y_fine)

R_coarse = np.sqrt(X_coarse_mesh**2 + Y_coarse_mesh**2)
Z_coarse = np.sin(R_coarse)
R_fine = np.sqrt(X_fine_mesh **2 + Y_fine_mesh **2)
Z_fine = np.sin(R_fine)

# First make a mapping/interpolation object..
interpolate_obj = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(X_coarse, Y_coarse, Z_coarse)
Z_fine_rectbiv = interpolate_obj(X_fine, Y_fine)

XY_coarse_list = np.concatenate([np.reshape(X_coarse_mesh, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(Y_coarse_mesh, (-1, 1))], axis=1)
XY_fine_list = np.concatenate([np.reshape(X_fine_mesh, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(Y_fine_mesh, (-1, 1))], axis=1)
Z_list = np.reshape(Z_coarse, (-1, 1))


z = scipy.interpolate.griddata(XY_coarse_list, Z_list, XY_fine_list, method='cubic')
Z_fine_griddata = np.reshape(z, (40, 40))

# Plot the surface.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X_coarse_mesh, Y_coarse_mesh, Z_coarse, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.title('coarse grid')
plt.show()

# Plot the surface on a finer grid
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X_fine_mesh, Y_fine_mesh, Z_fine_griddata-Z_fine, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.title('griddata')
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X_fine_mesh, Y_fine_mesh, Z_fine_rectbiv-Z_fine, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.title('RectBivariateSpline')
plt.show()
```